# How to create a MATLAB script with input parameters, but not yet a function?

Tags: matlab

As far as I know, one difference between a script and a function in MATLAB is that the variables in a script will be present in the workspace, whereas the variables in a function die as the function returns the result(s).

Sometimes, I need a script that takes in parameters to be invoked from a shell script. That is, I need the variables in the workspace, and hence, I cannot simply make my script a function.

In such a case, how can I have a script with parameters, but not yet a function? i.e., the script takes in parameters to run, and the variables in it appear in the workspace.

Comment: Define it as a function, then inside the function save the variables using `save` that you can load into the workspace once you are out of the function call?

Comment: check the functions `assingin` and `evalin`.

Comment: You are attempting to find a solution to a bad implementation. I recommend you use only functions and have your variables passed to other functions.

Comment: @m_power why is this a bad implementation??\

Comment: ­@FarticlePilter because from what I understand, you want a solution for transforming a script to act like a function. Without your example however, it is hard to propose a better implementation for what you are trying to do.

Comment: My usual approach for that is: use a script and decide on a set of workspace variables that will be used as "input" parameters for that script

Answer (score 0):

## If you want to browse the variable

you should make a breakpoint inside the function and step

## If you want to return the variable

you should return the variable as an left hand side argument

```
function [output1, output2] = test(input1, input2)
  variable_of_interest
end
```

Change it to

```
function [output1, output2, variable_of_interest] = test(input1, input2)
  variable_of_interest
end
```

## If you want to use it as a global variable

Check out http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html

## Finally, if you want to get all the variables inside the function,

#### Just convert the function into a script. i.e.

```
function [out, out...] = functionName(in, more_in)
    % Inside the function
    main...
end
```

into

```
    % Inside the function
    main...
```

#### And just call the script.

```
[out, moreout ...] = functionName(in, morein ...)
```

into

```
functionName;
```

`Note` Your the variable names must match.

Yes, just remove the first line and the last line (if there is a `end` clause which can be omitted) and call the script. Since the function name and the file name have to be the same, and MATLAB recognize the function/script by file name. It will work.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not as neat as I expect. I basically need to save the whole workspace. Returning everything seems a little bit ugly.

Comment: As @m_power mentioned, it is a very bad design scheme to make a function and pass all the variables inside the function. It is better to make it as a script.